# how to write substring to get the string from starting position to the end

Tags: pyspark

I want to extract the code starting from the 25<sup>th</sup> position to the end.

I tried:

```
df_1.withColumn("code", f.col('index_key').substr(25, f.length(df_1.index_key))).show()
```

But I got the below error message,

```
TypeError: startPos and length must be the same type. Got <class 'int'>
```

respectively:

```
<class 'pyspark.sql.column.Column'>
```

Any suggestion will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**`Using .substr:`**

Instead of **integer** value keep value in **`lit(<int>)`**(will be column type) so that we are passing both values of same type.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
#+---------+
#|index_key|
#+---------+
#|   abcdef|
#+---------+

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.withColumn("code",col("index_key").substr(lit(1),length(col("index_key")))).\
show()
#+---------+-------+
#|index_key|   code|
#+---------+-------+
#|  abcdefg|abcdefg|
#+---------+-------+
```

Another option is using **`expr`** and **`substring`** function.

**`Example:`**

```
df.withColumn("code",expr('substring(index_key, 1,length(index_key))')).show()
#+---------+------+
#|index_key|  code|
#+---------+------+
#|   abcdef|abcdef|
#+---------+------+
```